# Как при наведении на один блок добавить класс и ему и вообще другому блоку

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как при помощи CSS или JS при наведении на один блок изменить класс и ему и вообще другому блоку?

Вот, например, при на ведении на блок  содержащийся в  нужно добавить в блок ещё один класс и при этом в блоке вне   также добавить новых класс

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <div class="logo"><!--При наведении добавить класс чтобы получилось class="logo qwe"-->
        <a href="#">Лого</a>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul class="menu-widget"><!--При наведении на class="logo" добавить класс к class="menu-widget"чтобы получилось class="menu-widget asd"-->
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как вы пробовали решить даную задачу, или вам написать готовый код ?

Comment: Я с помощью подобного скрипта пытался 
$("").click(function() {
  $('').toggle();
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).length) {
    $('').hide();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
С помощью hover в css пробовал, уже много времени потратил на поиск и пробу различных способов, но из тех которые я находил они были связанны ток с блоками находящихся ну на одном уровне так сказать, на подобии выпадающего меню, а вот с изменением стилей из разных блоков не нахожу, а сам скок не пытаюсь не получается.
Вот и обращаюсь за помощью

Comment: Предлагаю начать с [этого](https://learn.javascript.ru/first-steps)

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно начать с малого, но у меня уже есть работа с определенными функциями и модулями, а вот со скриптом не могу справиться, а вот именно подобная операция мне сейчас очень нужна.
Если вам не трудно пожулуйста напишите, прошу

Comment: добавляете обработчик [ховера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951662/5610621) для нужного элемента, в котором делаете нужную вам логику(добавление класса другому элементу)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// забрали элемнты DOM в JS
const headerDiv = document.getElementById('hd');
const ul = document.getElementById('uld');

headerDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => { // вешаем событие наведения курсора и пишем функцию, в которой говорим что делать по событию
  headerDiv.classList.add('added');
  ul.classList.add('added');
});

// как вернуть всё в исходное состояние я думаю, что справишься сам.
```

```css
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.added {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <div id="hd" class="logo"><!--При наведении добавить класс чтобы получилось class="logo qwe"-->
        <a href="#">Лого. Hover here</a>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div>
  <div>
    <ul id="uld" class="menu-widget"><!--При наведении на class="logo" добавить класс к class="menu-widget"чтобы получилось class="menu-widget asd"-->
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большой